# An equation to create this graph/function? Something like ((x-y)/y)

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

I am trying to make some sort of function, which given two values, will determine the probability of something happening.

Currently, the equation is: probability = ((x-y)/y)

For example, if I had Stat 1 of 2400, and Stat 2 of 1600, I would get ((2400-1600)/1600)=0.5.

If I have ((3200-1600)/1600) I would get 1.0.

But the thing is I don't want to have a result of 1.0 at 3200. Maybe perhaps something like 0.667 or even 0.75 would be more feasible. I think you can put some sort of "weight" value part of the equation to adjust the probability, when (x-y) = y.

So something like:

((3200-1600)/1600)) * ??? * z = 0.667.
((3200-1600)/1600)) * ??? * z = 0.75.
((3200-1600)/1600)) = 1. (this one is what we have originally and I don't want)

Some function z that you can add on to the ((x-y)/y)

I hope I explained this properly

Comment: I am a bit unclear on what your exact goal is, there are many ways to achieve what you want (value constrained between $0$ and $1$). The thing that is important, assuming you want to allow for unbounded inputs (meaning they can be arbitrarily large), is what is known as end behavior of the mathematical model you choose to use. You want end behavior that tends to 0 or 1, and that the function is also bounded on it's domain by those values. One example that can be transformed to achieve this is the inverse tangent function.

Comment: Can you explain the context of this question? For example, are you calculating some probability or multiplier for a game based on player 'stats'? Are you designing some system? Often there will be a better way to do it which is more straightforward than your explanation.

Comment: I have a game where the probability of scoring a "critical strike" is dependent on the user's Luck stat versus the target's Luck stat. I don't want users to ever have >100% chance to score a Critical strike, so I am planning to somehow give some diminishing returns to that. So if I had 3200 luck, and my opponent had 1600, I don't want 100% crit rate (from a balance perspective). Maybe something like 67% or 75%. I would literally expect myself to have a Luck stat of over 10,000 to get somewhere even remotely close to 90% crit rate (and getting 10,000 in a stat in the game is near impossible).

Comment: @JustinBenfield The inverse tangent function is what I was looking for, sort of a x^3 graph, but rotated 90 degrees. How would I merge this inverse tangent function with what I have right now?

Comment: @shardulc notification

Comment: One problem with using $\dfrac{x-y}{y}$ when $y>x\geq 0$, you'll end  with a negative value as probability.  So you'd need to express probability as $\left|\dfrac{x-y}y\right|$

Comment: I cannot give a proper answer atm because the question is on hold, but the short version is this: arctan has domain $(-\infty,\infty)$ which is the range of $\frac{x-y}{x}$ and arctan's range is $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, so we need to adjust arctan's range to be $(0,1)$ and put your current expression inside the arctan. Those adjustments yield $p=\frac{1}{\pi}(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x-y}{x}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have the ratio $r = \frac{x-y}{y}$ and you want a function $f(r)$ with $f(0)=0$, $f(\frac12)=\frac23$ and $f(r) \to 1$ as $r \to \infty$, then one possibility is  $$f(r)=1-9^{-r}$$ equivalent to $1-\exp(-kr)$ where $k=\log_e 9$.

This would give $f\left(\frac{2400-1600}{1600}\right)=\frac23$ and $f\left(\frac{3200-1600}{1600}\right)=\frac89$, which may or may not meet your needs

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but how would I use this in terms of 'c', x and y? And is there a number to adjust the "weight" such that 3200-1600/1600 may return something other than 8/9 (for toggling/fine tuning purposes)?

Comment: @DonWarren $x$ and $y$ are already in the given formula. What do you mean by $c$? For fine-tuning, note that $k = 9$ above, but you can put any value greater than 1 and achieve different results. A value very close to 1 is probably what you are looking for because the function approaches 1 very slowly.

Comment: @DonWarren  you can change the $9$ or use $1-\exp(-kr)$ for different values of $k$ but there are many other possible functions

Comment: It took me a bit to understand how to use this answer of yours, but I finally get it. I've also played around with the value, comparing different types of equations (with different values from 9) and comparing it to y=x (which was the original formula I sort of had regarding ratios).